# Как на самом деле работает свойство prototype и оператор instanceof?

Tags: javascript

Очень смущает поведение оператора instanceof в JavaScript.
В документации написано, что он **проверяет цепочку прототипов на присутствие в ней определенного класса**.

Однако на практике я встречаю совершенно непонятное поведение. Например:

```
    function Noo() {}
    function Foo() {}
    Foo.prototype = Noo; // Задаем прототип
    alert(Foo.prototype) // Noo(){}

    var fooObj = new Foo();
    alert(fooObj.prototype); // Object. WTF?!
    alert(fooObj instanceof Noo); // false. WTF?!
```

Причём, что самое интересное, в дебагере в свойстве `_proto_` функция `Noo()`, то есть в цепочке прототипов она есть, так почему же `false`?

Далее, если дать функции `Foo()` прототип в виде объекта, используя ключевое слово new, то `intsanceof` отрабатывает ожидаемо:

```
// А теперь тоже самое, но создадим объект
Foo.prototype = new Noo();
fooObj = new Foo();
alert(fooObj instanceof Noo); // true. WTF?!
```

Почему так? В чем ключевое отличие?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте, чтоб у вас лишней путаницы не было в голове, уберем лишнее -

```js
function Noo() {}

console.log(Noo instanceof Noo);

console.log((new Noo()) instanceof Noo);
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: Есть только предположение. Похоже на то, что instanceof проверяет не наличие в определенных прототипов, а является ли определенный объект созданным с помощью определенной функции. Вы это хотели сказать?

Comment: @YesMan есть класс, есть инстанс класса, это разные вещи. Логично, что класс не является своим собственным инстансом. Вы же не можете себя родить?

Comment: Ну, то есть, мое предположение верно? Проверка идет на то, создан ли  определенный объект определенным конструктором где-то переходя от прототипа к прототипу?

Comment: @YesMan Да, вы на верном пути) я просто назвал классом конструктор, а инстансом - объект, с его помощью созданный.
Собственно instanse с английского - экземпляр

Comment: Могли бы оформить ответ развернуто, чтобы я мог отметить его как правильный? Для будущих поколений, так сказать. Всё таки, фрагмент кода без пояснений не для всех очевиден.